# How should I present awards I won as a co-author in my resume?

Tags: conference, cv, projects, awards

I'm a co-author on a project. The project has been presented at 2 conferences and won 2 awards. How should I present this information on my resume?

Comment: Personally I have a separate section in my CV for awards and prize, but I don't know if there is any kind of standard formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty free to format your resume as you like. If you list the publications in the publications section you can also refer to them from the awards section noting that it was joint work. Depending on your field, conference presentation could be worth a lot, or not. In Computer Science, they normally have high value.

But in the awards section you could say something like "*Optimal Widget Factorization* listed above was awarded the Best Paper award at CCCSC, 2017"

There are a number of other ways. One would be to footnote the paper in the publications listing with a footnote naming the award or even listing the award in parentheses in the listing itself.

Don't worry too much about how you do it, just so you don't give the impression there are two things when there is only one.

---

I'm assuming that it was the paper that won the award, as opposed to the individuals who wrote it. That would be the standard thing.